# Out of order rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I have a sequence of rows such as:

```
1
2
3
7
8
4
5
6
9
```

How can I identify the groups of ordered rows like that:

```
1    1
2    1
3    1
7    2
8    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
9    4
```

My sequence could have missing values, so I think I have to identify when a value is smaller than the previous (like 4<8), and from that value (4) find the start of the group that begin with (7), and so on. But I'm not quite sure how to formulate that in excel.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention, my data is real numbers and to contiguous, so I can't use something like "check if the next value is not previous+1". I used whole numbers just to make the example easier to visualized, in reality it is something like: {1.2,2.0,5.1,3.1,3.3,4.7,6.8,...}

Comment: so each group sequence contains 3 rows ? row 300 would fit into group 100 ?

Comment: No, a group could have 1 row, or any other number of rows. A group is a sequence of values that are in order. In my example, the groups are {1,2,3},{7,8},{4,5,6},{9}

Comment: oh, so you mean each continuous sequence is to be grouped ?

Comment: That is it. I'm not sure how to go around implementing this in excel.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you provide an example based on real data, instead of a non-representative example of made-up data.  Both the data and how you want it grouped.  I would have to guess as to how you would want your 2nd example grouped.

Comment: {{1.2,2.0},{5.1},{3.1,3.3,4.7},{6.8}}. I don't think what I want to do is possible in Excel. I trying a programmatically approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is see if data in column A is sequential without missing any numbers & that's why 7 after 3 in column A increments the count in column B.

Assuming your data starts in A1 then enter 1 into B1, then in B2 use the following formula:

```
=IF(A2=A1+1, B1, B1+1)
```

This checks if the value in A2 is A1+1, if it is then it returns the value from above otherwise it increases the count in B by 1.

You can just drag or fill this formula down.

Comment: My actual data is not discrete contiguous integral values. They are real numbers. I edited my question to include this information.

Comment: When to we increment in column B? In the simplified example going from 3 to 7 was deemed non-continuous, is it if the stepwise increment is greater than 1?

Comment: With this method, you need to start with a 1 in cell B1

Comment: When a new group is found, a group is a sequence of values that are in order. In my example, the groups are {1,2,3},{7,8},{4,5,6},{9}.

{7,8} gets its own group because there is another group that could be inserted before it ({4,5,6}).

Comment: ok but in your exanded example how do we know that 2.0 is grouped with 1.2 when we could have added {1.3, 1.4, 1.5} between them